# Is there a way to set Dragon Naturally Speaking 11 to dictate to an unfocused application?

Tags: focus, dragon-naturally-speaking

Does anyone know of a way in which to instruct Dragon to remain focused on a designated application regardless of its focus status instead of following focus changes? The primary use case we have is for doing multiple things at once, however if dragon follows a change in focus, then it becomes mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing this:

- Either you buy the Medical version of Dragon NaturallySpeaking where this is a built-in feature - though only for one hidden window
- or you buy an add-on called [dns.comfort](http://sonic-labs.net/en/index.html). There you'll need the option *SpeechLock* where you can set the focus of your speech input to any open application on your computer. Unfortunately, their website does not explain that too well, you'll need to conctact them to order this feature.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.quora.com/Dragon-Naturally-Speaking/How-can-I-make-Dragon-Speaking-type-in-one-windows-regardless-on-what-window-I-am-actively-using :

> Alan Tikwart:  "Contact the Verbble team … http://www.verbble.com - They
>   have a solution that is called TalkAnywhere available on Windows that
>   allows a user to talk literally anywhere you can put a cursor.  The
>   solution is asynchronous (backfilling) (vs. Dragon's synchronous /
>   blocking technology), so you can go as fast as you want. Verbble uses
>   Nuance (or any other speech engine).  It is awesome...ask about the
>   Rapid Fire feature, which further increases the speed."